# EF cannot convert linq to sql

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I installed Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug according to the tutorial and wanted to see how each query statement of ef core is converted into sql.

And added the following code in Context:

```
public partial class MyDbnContext : DbContext
{
         [Obsolete]
         public static readonly LoggerFactory LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] { new DebugLoggerProvider((_, __) => true) });
         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
         {
             base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
             optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory);
         }
}
```

But every time the query statement is executed, the corresponding sql statement does not appear on the console.

Please can someone guide me to implement it successfully

Comment: `DebugLoggerProvider` creates a logger that "writes messages in the debug output window only when a debugger is attached" ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.debug.debuglogger)). If that does not do what you want, then try `ConsoleLoggerProvider` instead. See e.g. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/logging-in-entityframework-core.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the SQL generated by EF Core to the console, you can also follow the following steps, taking a console program as an example.

Add the following code in Context (need to reference Microsoft.Extensions.Logging):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
=> optionsBuilder
    .UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Ef;Integrated Security=True;encrypt=false;")
    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
    .LogTo(message => Debug.WriteLine(message),
        new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name },
        LogLevel.Information);
```

At this time, the corresponding SQL statement will appear when starting the project console:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I am using the console program for testing